# How do I call PushModule.initModule? What is the second argument?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios

In iOS.

I am hitting this error.

> Fatal error: SFMCSdk.initModule() must be called before using
> PushModule

I don't know how to call `PushModule.initModule`.
How do I call PushModule.initModule? What is the second argument?

```
PushModule.initModule(config: configuration, components: [**What is this**])
```

Comment: Sorry, I solved the problem after reading LearningApp, I should have accessed it from SFMCSdk.mp.